# How can I create checkbox validation that only allows a user to Select a checkbox if a previous checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

// What I want to do is allow the user to select many checkboxes. In order to make a booking the user must select atleast one seat number checkbox(this checkbox has to be one or many of the seat number checkboxes). They can also select child,wheelchair or special diet, but in order to do so, the checkbox that belongs to the corresponding seat number must be checked. If it isnt a validation or popup must occur stating that the seat number must be checked. Meaning that if a user wants to check either special diet, wheelchair or child the seat number must be checked. If the user clicks the submit button without any checkboxes selected than a validation should occur or popup stating that atleast one checkbox must be selected.[THis is my current page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB3uU.png)

this is my nextpage.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>

td{

    padding-top: 10px; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
p{
font-size: 16px;

}
</style>
<body>
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<?php

       $str = $_GET['Confirm'];
       $array = (explode(",",$str)); 
      ?>


<h1>Booking Details</h1>

Flight Details:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Route_no
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $array[0] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        To_city</td>
        <td> <?php echo $array[1] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        From_city</td>
        <td> <?php echo $array[2] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Price</td>
        <td> $<?php echo $array[3] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["route_no"] = $array[0];
$_SESSION["to_city"] = $array[1];
$_SESSION["from_city"] = $array[2];
$_SESSION["price"] = $array[3];
echo "Session variables for this booking have been set.";
?>
<form action="Yourbookings.php" method="get">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Seat #</td>
    <td>Child </td>
    <td>WheelChair</td>
    <td>Special Diet</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Seat 1 <input type="checkbox" name="seat1" value="2"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="Child" value="Child1"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="WheelChair" value="WheelChair1"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="Special Diet" value="SpecialDiet1"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Seat 2 <input type="checkbox" name="seat2" value="1"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="Child2" value="Child2"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="WheelChair2" value="WheelChair2"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="Special Diet2" value="SpecialDiet2"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Seat 3 <input type="checkbox" name="seat3" value="seat3"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="Child3" value="Child3"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="WheelChair3" value="WheelChair3"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="Special Diet3" value="SpecialDiet3"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Seat 4 <input type="checkbox" name="seat4" value="seat4"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="Child4" value="Child14"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="WheelChair4" value="WheelChair4"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="Special Diet4" value="SpecialDiet4"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Seat 5 <input type="checkbox" name="seat5" value="seat5"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="Child5" value="Child5"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="WheelChair5" value="WheelChair5"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="Special Diet5" value="SpecialDiet5"> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
$_SESSION["price"] = $array[3];


?>

Total = $variable??


<input type="submit" name="Add booking" value="Add_booking">
</form>



</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, forget about all the alerts and such, just use arrayed check box keys:

```
    <tr>
        <td>Seat 1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat1[child]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat1[wheelchair]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat1[specialdiet]" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Seat 2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat2[child]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat2[wheelchair]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat2[specialdiet]" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Seat 3</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat3[child]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat3[wheelchair]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat3[specialdiet]" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Seat 4</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat4[child]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat4[wheelchair]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat4[specialdiet]" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
```

Upon submission your array will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [seat1] => Array
        (
            [child] => 1
            [wheelchair] => 1
        )

    [seat2] => Array
        (
            [wheelchair] => 1
        )

    [seat3] => Array
        (
            [wheelchair] => 1
            [specialdiet] => 1
        )

    [seat4] => Array
        (
            [child] => 1
            [wheelchair] => 1
            [specialdiet] => 1
        )

    [Add_booking] => Add_booking
)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on your clarification, you need some javascript (jQuery):

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/9e9embjt/

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).on('click',".seat_selector",function() {
        var thisBtn     =   $(this);
        var isChk       =   thisBtn.is(":checked");
        var thisWrap    =   thisBtn.parents('.seat_selector_wrap').find("input[type=checkbox]");
        if(isChk)
            thisWrap.attr("disabled",false);
        else {
            thisWrap.attr("disabled",true);
            thisBtn.attr("disabled",false);
        }

        var allSeats    =   $(".seat_selector");
        var disable     =   true;
        $.each(allSeats, function(k,v) {
            if($(v).is(":checked")) {
                disable = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

        $("#submitter").attr('disabled',disable);
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
</tr>
    <tr class="seat_selector_wrap">
    <td>Seat 1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat1[seat]" value="1" class="seat_selector" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat1[child]" value="1" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat1[wheelchair]" value="1" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat1[specialdiet]" value="1" disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="seat_selector_wrap">
    <td>Seat 2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat2[seat]" value="1" class="seat_selector" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat2[child]" value="1" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat2[wheelchair]" value="1" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat2[specialdiet]" value="1" disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="seat_selector_wrap">
    <td>Seat 3</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat3[seat]" value="1" class="seat_selector" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat3[child]" value="1" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat3[wheelchair]" value="1" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat3[specialdiet]" value="1" disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="seat_selector_wrap">
    <td>Seat 4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat4[seat]" value="1" class="seat_selector" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat4[child]" value="1" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat4[wheelchair]" value="1" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat4[specialdiet]" value="1" disabled /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="Add booking" value="Add_booking" id="submitter" disabled />
```

Comment: there must be validation it is a must

Comment: To what end do you need validation? To check that all 5 seats are checked off?

Comment: to ensure atleast one seatnumber checkbox is selected before clicking add_submit button and that in order for the user to select econ and or firstclass and or businessclass, the checkbox(i.e seatnumber) that corresponds with those three checkboxes(i.e the three checkboxes on the same row) must be selected first so that the user can then select any of the three checkboxes/ if you still dont understand please let me know.

Comment: So they need to check a seat first, then allow for any special options that go with that seat. So they could have 0 options, but must choose a seat, correct?

Comment: correct. and they can choose multiple seats aswell not just the one.

Comment: I appreciate the effort made, but there needs to be some sort of validation or popup showing the user that in order for the the 3 other checkboxes to be selected a seat number has to be selected. Youre on the right track, but there needs to be validation or a popup when a user selects one of the other three checkboxes when seatnumber hasnt been selected.

Comment: In this scenario, you can not even check the other boxes in the row without selecting a seat first, all the other boxes are disabled. Your scenario is impossible based on what I have.

Comment: Further to that, the submit button is disabled until you select a seat. There is no way to advance in this scenario without first selecting a seat. That is why no validation is need.

Comment: You are basing the logic of the form on the fact that everything by default is enabled. I think, there is no point in enabling everything at once then trying to direct the user backwards. You should have a build-up of events. User must do "A" before "B" activates.

Comment: I know your way may be better and more logical and more efficient. But in the end, I need a solution to what I need, even though it seems less effective less efficient. I need popups and validation instead of disabling the other checkboxes. I apologize if I didnt articulate myself properly.

Comment: It's all good. From what I have supplied, there should be enough to work with to get what you are looking to do. Between this answer and the other one I gave, there is a lot to work with with regards to getting what you are looking for with some JavaScript.